# Can you have multiple url.actions within one view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers and two models (completely separate).  I then have one view where I use an url.action to create a new record using the first controller and model.  I then have another url.action to create a record for the other controller and model.  My issue is that submitting one will submit the other.  Is it bad practice to use a url.action to display the create view - because it works well when I only use one url.action.  Or is it bad practice to have multiple.  How else could this goal be achieved without having to use another view?

the view is pretty straight forward.
....

```
<div>
@*@Html.Action("Create", "MPost", new { TaskId = Model.TaskId, TaskTitle = Model.Title })*@
</div>

<div>
@Html.Action("Vote", "Vote", new { TaskId = Model.TaskId})     
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using multiple `Html.Action()` calls within your Views, however you need to consider if that's the best option for you to use.

**Determining What You Want To Do**

[`Html.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx) is going to call the controller action when the View is initially rendered and it will perform whatever actions are in the View and then it may or may not return another View / Partial View.

You mentioned the following in your post :

> My issue is that submitting one will submit the other. Is it bad
>   practice to use a url.action to display the create view - because it
>   works well when I only use one url.action.

This sounds like you actually want these to function as links and when they are clicked that you want to call them. If that is the case, you may be better off either creating a link that points to the appropriate action via the [`Url.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) or [`Html.ActionLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) helpers :

```
<a href='Url.Action("Create", "MPost", new { TaskId = Model.TaskId, TaskTitle = Model.Title })'>Create New Post!</a>
```

These will perform basic `GET` requests to your Controller Action as you might expect. If you need to actually `POST` values, then you should consider using a `<form>` and submitting it :

```
<form action='@Url.Action("Vote", "Vote", new { TaskId = Model.TaskId})'>
      <input type='submit' value='Cast Your Vote!' />
</form>
```

Generally, if you have two separate URLs that you might be posting values to, you should consider placing them each within their own `<form>` to avoid any confusion or possibly posting to the wrong area. Using links will work just fine as well, but keep in mind that they will redirect the user to the View that is returned from the Controller Action that you are hitting.